# netlogo: asking turtles-on patch-here whether breed is the same

Tags: netlogo

Whenever two turtles with equal breeds are on the same patch, they should reproduce.

Therefore a turtle should be able to assess, whether it's alone on a patch and if not whether the other turtle is the same breed. 
This is what i've tried:

```
 ask turtles [
     if any? turtles-on patch-here with [ breed != [ breed ] of myself ] [
          ; do something
          ]
     ]
```

But i just don't get it right so that `turtles-on patch-here` is the right thing for `with`.
How would i do this properly?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: I'd know how to do it with multiple ifs or elseifs but the model i'm working on is relatively big so i'm trying to program as efficient as possible

Comment: what error are you getting or what it is actually doing? Try putting brackets in to help NetLogo work out precedence. Whenever I do combination agentset before a `with`, I usually toss in some brackets, so your line would be `if any? (turtles-on patch-here) with [ breed != [ breed ] of myself ]`

Comment: Thanks! With the brackets `(turtles-on patch-here)` there is an error message: `Only the observer can ASK the set of all turtles.`

Comment: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other

Comment: NetLogo doesn't allow turtles to `ask` something of all turtles - only the observer can do this.  It's hard to know without seeing your code, but, from the error message, it's likely you are having a turtle execute the `ask turtles`. Once you get the observer to make this ask, be careful that you don't "double reproduce".  If A initiates reproduction with B, then B shouldn't be allowed to initiate reproduction with A (or anyone else?)..

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were right the problem was not the code itself but that in the `to go` function i've asked the turtles something again which was then triggering this above function leading to the error. Now i exactly have the problem of the double reproduction, but i can't find out how to denote the two turtles, because both are reffering to themselves. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: One easy way might be to have a flag as a turtles-own variable, say `reproduced?`, which you first set to `false` for all turtles. Then, when two turtles reproduce, set `reproduced?` to `true` for both.  You would then ask only turtles who have `reproduced? = false` to look for turtles of the same breed on the same patch who also have `reproduced = false`.